# Fetching DB2 stored procedure cursor from jdbc

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, jdbctemplate

I have a standalone java application which invokes a DB2 Stored Procedure and it is working fine.I have to fetch couple of cursors from the stored procedure and I am using the following syntax

```
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(169, com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Types.CURSOR);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(170, com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Types.CURSOR);
```

I have my db2jcc.jar in my classpath.Compile time I donot have any error.While running the application I am getting an exception

Data type CURSOR is not supported on the target server. ERRORCODE=-4450, SQLSTATE=0A502

Any inputs please

Comment: I think the message is quite clear -- not all DB2 versions support the ref cursor data type. What DB2 version and platform are you connecting to? Are you sure that your procedure returns ref cursor variables, and not result sets? These are two different things.

Comment: @mustaccio yes thank you.They are resultsets and not cursors.I sorted it out